# Is there a way to get all text from the rendered page with JS?

Tags: javascript, text, text-extraction

Is there an (unobtrusive, to the user) way to get all the text in a page with Javascript? I could get the HTML, parse it, remove all tags, etc, but I'm wondering if there's a way to get the text from the alread rendered page.

To clarify, I don't want to grab text from a selection, I want the entire page.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879477/get-web-page-text-via-javascript

Answer (score 28):

All credit to [Greg W's answer](/questions/2986990/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-text-from-the-rendered-page-with-js#2987009), as I based this answer on his code, but I found that for a website *without inline style or script tags* it was generally simpler to use:

```
var theText = $('body').text();
```

as this grabs all text in all tags without one having to manually set every tag that might contain text.

Also, if you're not careful, setting the tags manually has the propensity to create duplicated text in the output as the each function will often have to check tags contained within other tags which results in it grabbing the same text twice. Using one selector which contains all the tags we want to grab text from circumvents this issue.

The caveat is that if there are inline style or script tags within the body tag it will grab those too.

## Update:

After reading [this article about `innerText`](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) I now think the absolute best way to get the text is plain ol vanilla js:

```
document.body.innerText
```

As is, this is not reliable cross-browser, but in controlled environments it returns the best results. Read the article for more details.

This method formats the text in a usually more readable manner and *does not* include style or script tag contents in the output.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you could do something like this, if you don't mind loading jQuery.

```
var theText;
$('p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5').each(function(){
  theText += $(this).text();
});
```

When its all done, "theText" should contain most of the text on the page. Add any relevant selectors I may have left out.

Comment: Actually, that's not a bad idea at all, I don't think I'll be needing any text outside these... However, won't this also pick up links inside paragraphs, etc?

Comment: I think that since we're using jQuery's text() method, it knows to strip those extra tags out for us. If we had used the html() method it would definitely carry the anchor tags along.

Comment: You could `switch` on element type that `this` is inside the each() and decide how to handle its content (the value from a drop down, the innerHTML from an anchor/paragraph/etc.)... You could get pretty fancy if you wanted to.

Comment: The point is to rely on the browser's rendering to get the text, though, not to get it from the HTML... Something like "select all text, get selected text".

Answer (score 1):

As an improvement to Greg W's answer, you could also remove 'undefined', and remove any numbers, considering they're not the words.

```
function countWords() {

    var collectedText;

    $('p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5').each(function(index, element){
        collectedText += element.innerText + " ";
    });   

    // Remove 'undefined if there'
    collectedText = collectedText.replace('undefined', '');

    // Remove numbers, they're not words
    collectedText = collectedText.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');

    // Get
    console.log("You have " + collectedText.split(' ').length + " in your document.");
    return collectedText;

}
```

This can be split into an array of words, a count of words; whatever, really.

Answer (score 0):

Select all text on page:

`window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(document.body)`

Now you can get this text as a string:

`const pageText = window.getSelection().toString()`

Answer (score 0):

*document.body.innerText* works, but you don't get any LFs so the result is a mess that cannot be corrected with any level of accuracy.

This script will replace a document with its rendered plain-text, including the LFs...

```
var D=Frame_ID.contentWindow.document, E=D.body.getElementsByTagName('*');

for(let i=0; i<E.length; i++){

 E[i].innerText=E[i].innerText;

}
```

NB: If you don't want to replace the current document you can clone each element in the loop, push it into an array, and then join the array with LFs.