# Is it possible to check whether WKWebView has a specific text on it in Swift?

Tags: ios, webkit, wkwebview

I am working on a project which is to show a website in a web view, the website is designed keeping iPhone in context and has only one URL where all the checks are done on server. I had a screen which has some text, for e.g. "Age". For this particular page, I want to add a tab bar button for sharing the application.

Comment: @the4kman Yes I am aware of that, I am using WKWebView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `evaluateJavaScript` with the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10606380/3151675), which returns all the text from the current page. After that, you can use `contains` to get whether the particular page contains the text you're looking for.

Don't forget to import **WebKit** and conform your class to `WKNavigationDelegate`.

```
func loadWebView() {
    let webView = WKWebView()
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.com")!)
    webView.load(urlRequest)
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerText") { result, error in
        if let resultString = result as? String,
            resultString.contains("Age") {
                //site contains the text "Age"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure of how to do this, can you post some useful links. Or a code snippet. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm. Superb Answer