# Get all visible text on on page?

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

I want to get all the visible text on a page. Visible text is defined as text that users can find by using Ctrl-F.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986990/is-there-a-way-to-get-all-text-from-the-rendered-page-with-js) advises using `document.body.innerText` but this includes non-visible text in `option` tags.

Is there a good solution for only getting visible text (Ctrl-F able) on a page?

Comment: Will this work  - Check for css display != none and  opacity != 0 ?

Comment: I'm currently using the `innerText` solution, but I guess I could manually iterate over all the DOM elements.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or any other libraries ?

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you

1. Get the body tag
2. Get all tags inside body
3. Iterate tags and get element of visible elements

   ```
    function isHidden(el) {
        var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
        return ((style.display === 'none') || (style.visibility === 'hidden'))
    }

    // get the body tag
    var body = document.querySelector('body');

    // get all tags inside body
    var allTags = body.getElementsByTagName('*');


    //console.log(allTags);


    for (var i = 0, max = allTags.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (isHidden(allTags[i])){
            // hidden
        }
        else { 
            console.log(allTags[i].innerText);
        }
    }
   ```