# Get number with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have a Javascript Bookmarlet, in which I want to grab a price that might be displayed on the current page.
So for example on shopping sites it could grab the price of an item the user is currently looking at.

I figured one way would be to grab all the text on the page, perhaps with something like [get web page text via javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879477/get-web-page-text-via-javascript)
And then from there filter to get just the number after a currency symbol is found (£,$ etc) which should in theory leave just the Price.

However I am now sure how I would go about actually filtering to just the number, and if this is at all the right way to go about this?

Comment: Hard to tell exactly with no specifications or code. But ajax might be a way to go to grab info from php (from js)

Comment: How would you distinguish between, say, `Price: $5` and `<del>Original Price: $5</del> Your Price: $3, you save $2!`

Comment: @Kolink I plan to have the script put the value it finds into a form text box, so the user can edit the value before passing it on, it would not need to be perfect and selecting the first number it finds with a currency value would most likely be good enough

Comment: With that approach you'll likely be chasing edge-cases for weeks, if not months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about get the text value of mark up?

E.g. Say you had:

```
<span id="price">£5.00</span>
```

You could do the following with jQuery:

```
$('#price').text();
```

Or vanilla javascript:

```
document.getElementById('price').innerText
```

Provided there is infact a wrapper around the text or you have access to the markup.

Comment: Yes this would be good, however I hope to have the script work on as many sites as possible that I have no control over. so they may not have a uniform id

Comment: Ah ok. But what if the sites had multiple prices on? The shops may have a related items section for example. You would still need specificity should that be the case.

Comment: I plan to have the script put the value it finds into a form text box, so the user can edit the value before passing it on, it would not need to be perfect and selecting the first number it finds with a currency value would most likely be good enough